# What will PCA and KernelPCA do when the number of rows of data is smaller than the number of columns?

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

Here's a simple test code of PCA:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

data = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
pca = PCA()
newData = pca.fit_transform(data)

eigenvalue, eigenvector = np.linalg.eig(np.cov(data.transpose()))

print eigenvalue
print eigenvector
```

The result is like this:

```
[  2.50000000e+00  -1.23259516e-32   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00]
[[ -4.47213595e-01   1.18714153e-16   2.46911666e-16   6.66612515e-33
    6.66612515e-33]
 [ -4.47213595e-01   8.66025404e-01   8.66025404e-01   6.66133815e-17
    2.49800181e-17]
 [ -4.47213595e-01  -2.88675135e-01  -2.88675135e-01  -5.77350269e-01
   -5.77350269e-01]
 [ -4.47213595e-01  -2.88675135e-01  -2.88675135e-01   7.88675135e-01
   -2.11324865e-01]
 [ -4.47213595e-01  -2.88675135e-01  -2.88675135e-01  -2.11324865e-01
    7.88675135e-01]]
```

Would you tell me what's the meaning of doing this kind of PCA or KernelPCA? And If we really have to deal with this kind of problem, how to make a better result?

Comment: It depends on how many components you want. For [PCA()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) `n_components == min(n_samples, n_features)`.

Comment: PCA and Kernel PCA will behave exactly the same no matter how many datapoints you have. The real question here is whether it is a good idea to perform PCA then and the answer is: No.